# DeMorgan's Law with Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

So I'm studying for an Assembly Language final tomorrow and I'm trying to simplify the following expression using Boolean Algebra. Here are the steps I've written so far, am I safe in assuming that this is a  proper process and answer? The answer my teacher wrote seems to get to the same result, but his application of DeMorgan's Law seems incorrect.

$$\begin{align}(x'+y)'(x+y)' & = (x''y')(x'y') \\
& = (xy')(x'y') \\
& = xy'x'y' \\
& = y'(xx') \\
& = y'
\end{align}$$

My teacher's process is this:

$$(x'+y)'(x+y)'$$
$$= (x'' + y')(x' + y')$$
$$= (x + y')(x' + y')$$
$$= xx' + xy' + x'y' + y'y'$$
$$= 0 + xy' + x'y' + y'y'$$
$$= xy' + x'y' + y'y'$$
$$= xy' + x'y' + y'$$
$$= y'$$

He claims "$(x'' + y')(x' + y')$" is done using DeMorgan's Law, but is that correct? Wouldn't it actually the first step in my process?

Comment: Shouldn't your process end $y'(xx') = y' 0 = 0$? And you should probably say if $+$ means 'or' or 'xor'.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that your teacher has used [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) incorrectly and so his answer is also wrong. Your solution in the last step is wrong. You must know that $x\bar x=0$ and then $0\bar y=0$.